# Trying to run sql queries on postgres database in linux but get Fatal: database "<db name>" does not exist but docker ps shows it does exist

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

This is the output from running `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS       PORTS                    NAMES
be9d3d7bcfe0   ruby:2.5-stretch      "bash -c 'rm -f tmp/…"   4 days ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   api-master_app_1
2c984adc35c9   postgres:9.6-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago   Up 3 hours   5432/tcp                 api-master_db_1
```

I now want to connect to `api-master_db_1` so I run `sudo docker exec -it api-master_db_1 psql -U postgres` which I know worked because the command line now says `postgres=#` Then I try to connect to the database using `\c api-master_db_1` and it says `FATAL:  database "lcbo-api-master_db_1" does not exist`

I am trying to run some sql queries on the database.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The database name is wrong. It is given in the .env as I am using ruby on rails. I still don't know why there is a difference between what is given in the .env file and what is shown by `docker ps`. If anyone can explain that to me. I would appreciate it.